# Poco - using removeObserver safely

Tags: c++, multithreading, poco-libraries

I have a notification centre in an Activity thread:

```
Poco::NotificationCentre nc;   // publicly visible

// (thread main loop which will post notifications from time to time)
```

and also multiple worker threads which act on the notification. However those threads waiting for notification may also need to be signalled externally to exit at any time. So I have got the following in my worker threads  (again this is pseudocode omitting some details for clarity)

```
Poco::Event event;
std::string s;
MyNotificationClass notifier{event, s};  // holds those by reference
Poco::NObserver<MyNotificationClass, MyNotification> obs(notifier, &MyNoficationClass::func);

nc.addObserver(obs);
event.wait();
nc.removeObserver(obs);

return s;
```

The notification class is:

```
struct MyNotificationClass
{
    MyNotificationClass(Poco::Event &ev, std::string &s): ev(ev), s(s) {}
    void func(const Poco::AutoPtr<MyNotification> &p)
    {
        s = p->s;
        ev.set();
    }
    Poco::Event &ev;
    std::string &s;
};
```

What I am worried about is that even after `removeObserver` is called in the worker thread, the notification centre might have been simultaneously having a notification posted to it, so the object `s` in the function that the worker thread has just `return`ed from might get accessed after it has been destroyed.

My question is: is this a valid concern, and if so, what should I do to make sure that no notification will occur after the `return` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: since `removeObserver()` is [disabling](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/NotificationCenter.cpp#L51) the removed observer, the above code is safe. The answer below left for the record to make sense of the comments section.

---

Original answer:

It is a valid concern - the worker thread function can get preempted between the add/removeObserver() calls. Since `postNotification()` [makes a copy](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/NotificationCenter.cpp#L74)* of all the observers' pointers, if there are multiple notifications from other threads, the pointer to your observer may still be in one or more copy list(s) after you call `removeObserver()` (or even after the function returns).

Now, there is no need to worry about the observer being accessed after the function returns because it is [cloned](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/NObserver.h#L106) into a [SharedPtr](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/NotificationCenter.cpp#L40) by the NotificationCenter. There is, however, a concern about the notification handler being called at that time because NObserver holds its [naked address](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/NObserver.h#L52). To prevent bad things happen, call `obs.disable()` before returning from the function - that will [disarm](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/NObserver.h#L82) the notification handling for any pending notifications in a thread-safe fashion.

---

* <sub>For performance reasons - we do not want to block the rest of the NotificationCenter while all the notification handlers are executing.</sub>

Comment: sorry, where do I call `disable()` ?

Comment: Anywhere after ```event.wait()```, probably best as soon as possible.

Comment: You mean `obs.disable()` there? OK. You mentioned that the NotificationCenter takes a copy of the observer, so would there still be a window of opportunity where a notification might have been started in the NotificationCenter (perhaps currently notifying another thread and hasn't got to this worker yet) and has already taken a copy, so it would still think this worker's observer is not disabled?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is ```observer```, not ```notifier.disable()```. I'll fix it in the answer. As for the second part of the question, ```NObserver::disable/notify()``` are protected by mutex, so if a thread is executing ```notify()```, ```disable()``` will wait.

Comment: OK, it should work fine given that mutex . Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: The solution I gave you should be safe, but I don't know enough about the rest of your application to make a good judgement if there is a better way of arranging things.

Comment: I had a problem implementing your suggestion. Calling `obs.disable(); nc.removeObserver(obs);` actually caused the observer to not be removed, with horrible effects as you can imagine.  To make it work I had to do `nc.removeObserver(obs); obs.disable();` . (Although I have not attempted to test whether this order still solves my original issue)

Comment: Looking at it again, I see that disable() is actually [called](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/NotificationCenter.cpp#L51) within removeObserver(), so the explicit call to it is unnecessary - i.e. your original code is safe. I don't see how calling it explicitly before the removeObserver() call could cause problems, though - could be a bug.